# Controllers fail during execution when using octomap with Moveit

Tags: moveit, ros-control, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using MoveIt with the default `RRTConnectkConfigDefault` motion planning library. I have a 6 DoF arm to which I pass target poses using roscpp's MoveGroupInterface. I'm using ros_control and have created my own Fake Controllers of the type `FollowJointTrajectory`. The target poses are acquired from the readings of a depth camera in Gazebo.

By default, I do not use the octomap using the depth cam. In this cases, MoveIt is able to generate the plans and also execute them successfully. I can see the arm moving in Rviz. I do not have an arm in Gazebo, it's only loaded in Rviz.

When I use the octomap, MoveIt can generate the plans, but fails during execution. All the joint states are being published on topic `/joint_states`. The same code works when I remove the sensors.yaml file and don't use the octomap. The controllers are up. I don't see any other errors in the terminal. Please help me identify the cause.

EDIT:
When I increase the resolution of the octomap from 0.01m to 0.05m, then suddenly things start to work? I changed the value in moveit_config/sensor_manager.launch file as so:

```
<param name="octomap_resolution" type="double" value="0.05" />
```

I'd like to make things work at 0.01m resolution, it looks granular enough.

---

Here are the error messages:
Error from MoveGroupInterface terminal where I pass in commands:

```
[ INFO] [1524323290.317619120, 261.964000000]: Ready to take commands for planning group arm.
[ INFO] [1524323293.819272021, 265.299000000]: 3D Co-ords of next target: X: 0.487010, Y: -0.132180, Z:-0.215447
[ INFO] [1524323303.789838914, 275.190000000]: ABORTED: Solution found but controller failed during execution
```

Error from the MoveIt terminal:

```
  [ INFO] [1524323029.558940862, 3.456000000]: Starting scene monitor
  [ INFO] [1524323029.562571287, 3.460000000]: Listening to '/move_group/monitored_planning_scene'
  [ INFO] [1524323033.952942898, 7.842000000]: Constructing new MoveGroup connection for group 'arm' in namespace ''
  [ INFO] [1524323035.143276258, 9.027000000]: Ready to take commands for planning group arm.
  [ INFO] [1524323035.143337694, 9.027000000]: Looking around: no
  [ INFO] [1524323035.143357118, 9.027000000]: Replanning: no
  [New Thread 0x7fffbef7e700 (LWP 20461)]
  [Wrn] [Publisher.cc:141] Queue limit reached for topic /gazebo/empty/pose/local/info, deleting message. This warning is printed only once.
  [ WARN] [1524323072.113526614, 45.706000000]: Failed to fetch current robot state.
  [ INFO] [1524323072.113676595, 45.706000000]: Planning request received for MoveGroup action. Forwarding to planning pipeline.
  Debug:   Starting goal sampling thread
  [New Thread 0x7fffb3fff700 (LWP 21008)]
  Debug:   Waiting for space information to be set up before the sampling thread can begin computation...
  [ INFO] [1524323072.116232595, 45.709000000]: Planner configuration 'arm[RRTConnectkConfigDefault]' will use planner 'geometric::RRTConnect'. Additional configuration parameters will be set when the planner is constructed.
  Debug:   The value of parameter 'longest_valid_segment_fraction' is now: '0.0050000000000000001'
  Debug:   The value of parameter 'range' is now: '0'
  Debug:   arm[RRTConnectkConfigDefault]: Planner range detected to be 4.017020
  Info:    arm[RRTConnectkConfigDefault]: Starting planning with 1 states already in datastructure
  Debug:   arm[RRTConnectkConfigDefault]: Waiting for goal region samples ...
  Debug:   Beginning sampling thread computation
  Debug:   Stopped goal sampling thread after 10 sampling attempts
  Debug:   arm[RRTConnectkConfigDefault]: Waited 0.040278 seconds for the first goal sample.
  [Thread 0x7fffb3fff700 (LWP 21008) exited]
  Info:    arm[RRTConnectkConfigDefault]: Created 4 states (2 start + 2 goal)
  Info:    Solution found in 0.043073 seconds
  Info:    SimpleSetup: Path simplification took 0.005992 seconds and changed from 3 to 17 states
  [ INFO] [1524323075.985180447, 49.557000000]: Execution request received for ExecuteTrajectory action.
  [ WARN] [1524323076.985406204, 50.550000000]: Failed to validate trajectory: couldn't receive full current joint state within 1s
  [ INFO] [1524323076.985470962, 50.550000000]: Execution completed: ABORTED
  [ WARN] [1524323081.883843029, 55.422000000]: Failed to fetch current robot state.
  [ INFO] [1524323081.883937069, 55.422000000]: Planning request received for MoveGroup action. Forwarding to planning pipeline.
```

Here's my sensors.yaml file:

```
# Add a depth camera to Rviz
sensors:
- sensor_plugin: occupancy_map_monitor/PointCloudOctomapUpdater
  point_cloud_topic: /camera/depth_registered/points
  max_range: 5
  padding_offset: 0.01
  padding_scale: 1.0
  point_subsample: 1
  filtered_cloud_topic: output_cloud
# this last topic is just to debug, having it adds processing time
```

And here's my controllers.yaml file:

```
controller_list:
    - name: "robot_follow_joint_trajectory_controller"
      action_ns: follow_joint_trajectory
      type: FollowJointTrajectory
      default: true
      joints:
          - robot_link1_joint
          - robot_link2_joint
          - robot_link3_joint
          - robot_link4_joint
          - robot_link5_joint
          - robot_link5_2_joint
```

Here's my robot_moveit_controller_manager.launch.xml

```
<launch>
  <!-- <arg name="moveit_controller_manager" default="moveit_simple_controller_manager/MoveItSimpleControllerManager" /> -->
  <arg name="moveit_controller_manager" default="moveit_ros_control_interface::MoveItControllerManager" />
  
  <param name="moveit_controller_manager" value="$(arg moveit_controller_manager)" />

  <rosparam file="$(find greppy_moveit_6dof)/config/controllers.yaml" />
</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/289286/controllers-fail-during-execution-when-using-octomap-with-moveit/) by [Shreeyak](https://answers.ros.org/users/30210/shreeyak/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-04-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The octomap pointcloud updater locks the planning scene during updates. I'm going to take a guess and say that you have a depth sensors publishing pointclouds at 20 to 30 Hz. If that is the case, the 'rest of MoveIt' doesn't get a chance to do some useful work before the updater locks the scene again.

Try decreasing the framerate and see if that works any better.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Shreeyak](https://answers.ros.org/users/30210/shreeyak/) on 2018-04-21**:
I'm publishing the point clouds at 6Hz and am running on a fairly powerful PC. Here's a snippet from my camera.gazebo.xacro file where I configure the depth cam plugin:

`<update_rate>6.0</update_rate>`

**Comment by [Shreeyak](https://answers.ros.org/users/30210/shreeyak/) on 2018-04-21**:
Same value also in the `libgazebo_ros_openni_kinect.so` plugin config, 6Hz.

**Comment by [Shreeyak](https://answers.ros.org/users/30210/shreeyak/) on 2018-04-21**:
Also, if I were to use a real depth camera, like the realsense, how would I configure it? Would I need to limit the framerate on the real camera as well?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-22**:
Just to test, set the framerate to `1.0` Hz. See what happens. The fact that lowering the resolution of the octomap helps suggests this has something to do with processing capacity.